# Play Video in Bootstrap Modal Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

I am trying to play a mp4 video  in the bootstrap modal pop-up.

The video is placed in the folder of my project.

The problem is , when I give the path of the video from the project's folder , nothing happens i.e. the video is not played :

Here is the snapshot of the pop-up[image]

I tried the following code :

```
  <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title">SECRETS OF SUPERIOR CUSTOMER SERVICE (July 22, 2016)</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                   
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>Departments/HR/Presentations/Credit/csp_pre.mp4"></iframe>

</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But , if I change the **Src** to some thing like :

```
http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4
```

The video is played .

What could be the problem ?

as the video is playing fine when I give the source from any online link.

Please help me .

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I also tried `video` tag instead of `iframe` but still problem is same if i give the source from folder :

```
<div class="modal-body">                   
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item"> 
                        <source src="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>Departments/HR/Presentations/Credit/csp_pre.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>


</div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace iframe with "video" and "source" tags as show below.

```
<video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item"> 
<!--replace this sample with your video-->
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

double check your path please. It works for me.

Comment: it is also working for me if i give the path o any online link..but when i give the path of the video from local folder , nothing happens.

Comment: I've edited my question you can see it , i've added the code with your suggested approach

Comment: Mmm. it is weird. Can you try to use for your path something like `http://localhost/Departments/HR/Presentations/Credit/csp_pre.mp4`

Comment: path is not the problem because i've checked it by giving wrong path then its showing web page is not displayed

Comment: BTW which web server are you using in local?

Comment: ..and are you sure that you are able to play that video csp_pre.mp4? Sorry I am trying to guess which is the issue here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581841/html5-video-tag-not-working-with-asp-net-c-sharp-2-0